# Update an image and keep the old one if the field is empty

Tags: image, symfony, file-upload, doctrine, twig

I have a form in my administration interface that allows me to publish an article by uploading an image and I have another form that allows me to edit an article.

When I modify my article, I would like to keep the previous image if the field is empty (so "null") or instantiate my new image by deleting the previous image if there was one, but I did not succeed ..

Currently, if I modify my article leaving my field image blank, doctrine defines my field image_id to NULL in the database.

I have an entity "Image" related to OneToOne with my entity "Article" and EditArticleType which sets the data of the current item to its default value.

My controller :

```
public function modifierArticleAction(Article $article, Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $form = $this->createForm(EditArticleType::class, $article);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            // $file récupère l'image
            $file = $article->getImage();
            $file2 = $article->getImage2();
            $file3 = $article->getImage3();
            $file4 = $article->getImage4();
            $file5 = $article->getImage5();
            $file6 = $article->getImage6();
            $file7 = $article->getImage7();
            $file8 = $article->getImage8();
            $file9 = $article->getImage9();
            $file10 = $article->getImage10();

            if($file !== null && ($file instanceof UploadedFile) === true) {
                $fileName = md5(uniqid('img_', true));
                $fileExtension = $file->guessExtension();
                $nomImageCompletFile = $fileName . '.' . $fileExtension;

                $file->move(
                    $this->getParameter('articles_images_directory'),
                    $nomImageCompletFile
                );

                setKey('xxx');
                $tinified = fromFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile);
                $tinified->toFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile);

                $image = new Image();
                $image->setExtension($fileExtension);
                $image->setFile($fileName);
                $em->persist($image);
                $article->setImage($image);
            }

            if($file2 !== null && ($file2 instanceof UploadedFile) === true) {
                $file2Name = md5(uniqid('img_', true));
                $file2Extension = $file2->guessExtension();
                $nomImageCompletFile2 = $file2Name . '.' . $file2Extension;

                $file2->move(
                    $this->getParameter('articles_images_directory'),
                    $nomImageCompletFile2
                );

                setKey('xxx');
                $tinified = fromFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile2);
                $tinified->toFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile2);

                $image2 = new Image();
                $image2->setExtension($file2Extension);
                $image2->setFile($file2Name);
                $em->persist($image2);
                $article->setImage2($image2);
            }

            if($file3 !== null && ($file3 instanceof UploadedFile) === true) {
                $file3Name = md5(uniqid('img_', true));
                $file3Extension = $file3->guessExtension();
                $nomImageCompletFile3 = $file3Name . '.' . $file3Extension;

                $file3->move(
                    $this->getParameter('articles_images_directory'),
                    $nomImageCompletFile3
                );

                setKey('xxx');
                $tinified = fromFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile3);
                $tinified->toFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile3);

                $image3 = new Image();
                $image3->setExtension($file3Extension);
                $image3->setFile($file3Name);
                $em->persist($image3);
                $article->setImage3($image3);
            }

            if($file4 !== null && ($file4 instanceof UploadedFile) === true) {
                $file4Name = md5(uniqid('img_', true));
                $file4Extension = $file4->guessExtension();
                $nomImageCompletFile4 = $file4Name . '.' . $file4Extension;

                $file4->move(
                    $this->getParameter('articles_images_directory'),
                    $nomImageCompletFile4
                );

                setKey('xxx');
                $tinified = fromFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile4);
                $tinified->toFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile4);

                $image4 = new Image();
                $image4->setExtension($file4Extension);
                $image4->setFile($file4Name);
                $em->persist($image4);
                $article->setImage4($image4);
            }

            if($file5 !== null && ($file5 instanceof UploadedFile) === true) {
                $file5Name = md5(uniqid('img_', true));
                $file5Extension = $file5->guessExtension();
                $nomImageCompletFile5 = $file5Name . '.' . $file5Extension;

                $file5->move(
                    $this->getParameter('articles_images_directory'),
                    $nomImageCompletFile5
                );

                setKey('xxx');
                $tinified = fromFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile5);
                $tinified->toFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile5);

                $image5 = new Image();
                $image5->setExtension($file5Extension);
                $image5->setFile($file5Name);
                $em->persist($image5);
                $article->setImage5($image5);
            }

            if($file6 !== null && ($file6 instanceof UploadedFile) === true) {
                $file6Name = md5(uniqid('img_', true));
                $file6Extension = $file6->guessExtension();
                $nomImageCompletFile6 = $file6Name . '.' . $file6Extension;

                $file6->move(
                    $this->getParameter('articles_images_directory'),
                    $nomImageCompletFile6
                );

                setKey('xxx');
                $tinified = fromFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile6);
                $tinified->toFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile6);

                $image6 = new Image();
                $image6->setExtension($file6Extension);
                $image6->setFile($file6Name);
                $em->persist($image6);
                $article->setImage6($image6);
            }

            if($file7 !== null && ($file7 instanceof UploadedFile) === true) {
                $file7Name = md5(uniqid('img_', true));
                $file7Extension = $file7->guessExtension();
                $nomImageCompletFile7 = $file7Name . '.' . $file7Extension;

                $file7->move(
                    $this->getParameter('articles_images_directory'),
                    $nomImageCompletFile7
                );

                setKey('xxx');
                $tinified = fromFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile7);
                $tinified->toFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile7);

                $image7 = new Image();
                $image7->setExtension($file7Extension);
                $image7->setFile($file7Name);
                $em->persist($image7);
                $article->setImage7($image7);
            }

            if($file8 !== null && ($file8 instanceof UploadedFile) === true) {
                $file8Name = md5(uniqid('img_', true));
                $file8Extension = $file8->guessExtension();
                $nomImageCompletFile8 = $file8Name . '.' . $file8Extension;

                $file8->move(
                    $this->getParameter('articles_images_directory'),
                    $nomImageCompletFile8
                );

                setKey('xxx');
                $tinified = fromFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile8);
                $tinified->toFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile8);

                $image8 = new Image();
                $image8->setExtension($file8Extension);
                $image8->setFile($file8Name);
                $em->persist($image8);
                $article->setImage8($image8);
            }

            if($file9 !== null && ($file9 instanceof UploadedFile) === true) {
                $file9Name = md5(uniqid('img_', true));
                $file9Extension = $file9->guessExtension();
                $nomImageCompletFile9 = $file9Name . '.' . $file9Extension;

                $file9->move(
                    $this->getParameter('articles_images_directory'),
                    $nomImageCompletFile9
                );

                setKey('xxx');
                $tinified = fromFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile9);
                $tinified->toFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile9);

                $image9 = new Image();
                $image9->setExtension($file9Extension);
                $image9->setFile($file9Name);
                $em->persist($image9);
                $article->setImage9($image9);
            }

            if($file10 !== null && ($file10 instanceof UploadedFile) === true) {
                $file10Name = md5(uniqid('img_', true));
                $file10Extension = $file10->guessExtension();
                $nomImageCompletFile10 = $file10Name . '.' . $file10Extension;

                $file10->move(
                    $this->getParameter('articles_images_directory'),
                    $nomImageCompletFile10
                );

                setKey('xxx');
                $tinified = fromFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile10);
                $tinified->toFile($this->getParameter('articles_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageCompletFile10);

                $image10 = new Image();
                $image10->setExtension($file10Extension);
                $image10->setFile($file10Name);
                $em->persist($image10);
                $article->setImage10($image10);
            }

            $slugify = new Slugify();
            $article->setTitre($article->getTitre());
            $article->setIntroduction($article->getIntroduction());
            $article->setContenu($article->getContenu());
            $article->setSlug($slugify->slugify($article->getTitre()));

            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Votre article a bien été modifié :)');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_sg_modifier_article', ['id' => $id]);
        }

        return $this->render(
            'AdminSGBundle:page:modifier-article.html.twig', [
                                                               'form'            => $form->createView(),
                                                               'articleToUpdate' => $article,
                                                           ]
        );
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

In you article entity try to edit each image field like this:

```
public function setImage($image)
{
    if (!is_null($image)) {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

...

```
public function setImage10($image)
{
    if (!is_null($image)) {
        $this->image10 = $image;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This logic must prevent setting the image entity if null.